# node-red and watson Conversation service. Error:not authorized. call to watson conversation service failed

Tags: slack, node-red, watson-conversation

I want to create a slack bot with node-red and Conversation service of Watson. This is my code:

```
    [
   {
      "id":"92984fcb.13597",
      "type":"http in",
      "z":"f83b7887.f92208",
      "name":"watson slack",
      "url":"/watson-rg-1",
      "method":"post",
      "swaggerDoc":"",
      "x":96,
      "y":116.35000610351562,
      "wires":[
         [
            "119d86bd.3ce22d"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"19d684b0.ceb487",
      "type":"http request",
      "z":"f83b7887.f92208",
      "name":"slack response",
      "method":"POST",
      "ret":"txt",
      "url":"https://hooks.slack.com/services/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",
      "tls":"",
      "x":782,
      "y":126.58999633789062,
      "wires":[
         [

         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"119d86bd.3ce22d",
      "type":"switch",
      "z":"f83b7887.f92208",
      "name":"Command parser",
      "property":"payload.text",
      "propertyType":"msg",
      "rules":[
         {
            "t":"regex",
            "v":"^!coin",
            "vt":"str",
            "case":false
         },
         {
            "t":"else"
         }
      ],
      "checkall":"true",
      "outputs":2,
      "x":148,
      "y":203.27999877929687,
      "wires":[
         [
            "c1ef9e78.1efb1"
         ],
         [
            "9d1c215b.7e936",
            "1fd76cf2.10950f"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"c1ef9e78.1efb1",
      "type":"function",
      "z":"f83b7887.f92208",
      "name":"real payload filter",
      "func":"return {\n    payload: Math.random() >= 0.5 ? \"heads\" : \"Tails\"\n};",
      "outputs":1,
      "noerr":0,
      "x":416,
      "y":282.2799987792969,
      "wires":[
         [
            "7b8c968d.58d104"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"7b8c968d.58d104",
      "type":"function",
      "z":"f83b7887.f92208",
      "name":"watson slack message",
      "func":"var text = {\n    text: msg.payload,\n    username : \"watson\"\n};\nreturn {\n    payload : JSON.stringify(text)\n};\n",
      "outputs":1,
      "noerr":0,
      "x":644,
      "y":198.27999877929687,
      "wires":[
         [
            "19d684b0.ceb487"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"9d1c215b.7e936",
      "type":"function",
      "z":"f83b7887.f92208",
      "name":"Get user context",
      "func":"msg.payload = msg.payload.text;\nmsg.user = \"toto\";\n//msg.params.context = {};\nreturn msg;",
      "outputs":1,
      "noerr":0,
      "x":332,
      "y":448,
      "wires":[
         [
            "f9fc1260.dd5a",
            "446d3ae.e966804"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"f9fc1260.dd5a",
      "type":"watson-conversation-v1",
      "z":"f83b7887.f92208",
      "name":"",
      "workspaceid":"",
      "multiuser":false,
      "context":true,
      "x":512,
      "y":448,
      "wires":[
         [
            "d7f5e507.82bf18",
            "c5685f38.2a269"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"d7f5e507.82bf18",
      "type":"function",
      "z":"f83b7887.f92208",
      "name":"Handle response",
      "func":"var user = msg.user;\nvar convContext = flow.get('convContexts')||{};\n\nconvContext[user] = msg.payload.context;\n\nmsg.payload = msg.payload.output.text.join(\"\\n\");\n\nflow.set('convContexts',convContext);\n\nreturn msg;",
      "outputs":"1",
      "noerr":0,
      "x":712,
      "y":448,
      "wires":[
         [
            "7b8c968d.58d104"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"446d3ae.e966804",
      "type":"debug",
      "z":"f83b7887.f92208",
      "name":"getUserCtx",
      "active":true,
      "console":"false",
      "complete":"payload",
      "x":505,
      "y":356.5299987792969,
      "wires":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"c5685f38.2a269",
      "type":"debug",
      "z":"f83b7887.f92208",
      "name":"AfterConv",
      "active":true,
      "console":"false",
      "complete":"payload",
      "x":677,
      "y":508.52996826171875,
      "wires":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"1fd76cf2.10950f",
      "type":"debug",
      "z":"f83b7887.f92208",
      "name":"slack payload",
      "active":true,
      "console":"false",
      "complete":"payload",
      "x":135,
      "y":388.5299987792969,
      "wires":[

      ]
   }
]
```

[image: screen shot of nodes]

But when I test. The first branch works (I did it just to test if the link between slack and node-red works or not) but the other one (with conversation node) doesn't work.

I have two errors:

1. call to watson conversation service failed
2. Error:not authorized

Comment: Hi - you don't need to cross post to both here and the node-red mailing list. Please be aware you've shared your workspaceid in both places so anyone can now access your instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for  your comment. I edited the code here and I deleted the workspace_id. I deleted also my post in the node-red mailing list.

Comment: The workspace id is still visible in the question edit history. If you have posted this to the mailing list you will do better to delete this question entirely

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing the issue. Please note, it might be because the username and the password in the conversation node have to be set to the **credentials of the conversation service** and not the bluemix credentials